# Crash during Twilio chat client shutdown on Android 8.0 (API 26, Oreo)

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

On Android 8.0, I am getting a consistent crash when calling `client.shutdown()`, with the following error message:

```
A/libc: invalid pthread_t 0x7dd83384f0 passed to libc
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28040 (RxCachedThreadS)
```

The [pthread implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/bionic/pthread_internal.cpp) returns null pre-8.0 but fatally crashes on >=8.0 when the thread is not found, I believe this is related.

Potentially useful lines from `ChatClient.setLogLevel`:

```
W/TWC: TNRegNotificationCtxSession:       540533023984 | 10/04/16:57:35.623 | WARNING  | 26     | TNRegNotificationCtxSession | Could not operate with notification context in twilsock. Error 9
E/TWC: TNWebsocket:       540501275888 | 10/04/16:57:35.624 | CRITICAL | 9      | TNWebsocket | Received error while waiting for message: Net Exception
```

I can provide the full logs if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio rep here, `(RxCachedThreadS)` are you using some RxJava in your app?

In any case, providing logs as per [this howto](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/REPORT_BUGS.md) is perhaps the best way forward.

JFYI: SO is probably not the best place for bug reports and crash investigations, so please open a ticket [on github here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/issues) and we'll be able to do it there. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll file an issue on github. I saw the howto but it was unclear what "send to Twilio" meant in that context. We are using RxJava, but the crash still occurs when `shutdown()` is called outside of an rx chain.

Comment: This should now be fixed.